# Open loop on 05 f250 5.4 3v triton

Tags: ford, power-loss, f-250, open-loop

I was looking at the live data on my Blu driver because I'm having a tough time pulling a trailer and climbing hills. The truck just bogs down and boosts rpms. While I was traveling up a hill, it posts an open loop status. I was going about 60 mph at the time. If I let of the gas and let it shift gears, it closes and seems to go back to normal, but when pulling a trailer off course, I can't let off the gas and the other day it momentarily posted a fuel rail pressure sensor failure. Otherwise, it idles fine, drives fine, seams very smooth other than the normal can phaser tick in the heads.

Any idea as to why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't think it going into open loop is where you need to be looking for your issue. The reason I say this is because of the "Fuel System Status" at the bottom which states the possible reasons (in parens). The one which stands out to me is *power enrichment*, which is what it needs when towing a load and climbing. The fuel pressure sensor is probably where I'd look.

Comment: I actually bought one today just in case, but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Also, thanks for the welcome! I haven't been on this site in a very long time, and it was in programming, so please bare with me in my ignorance.